# where to specify cluster details when using elastic search gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I want to access the data in `Elastic Search Cluster` from my `rails` application. Lets say server is running at `http://localhost:9200` and I want to access the end point `http://localhost:9200/location/type`.

The following this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/ruby-api/current/_the_ruby_client.html) and came across this example:

```
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true

client.cluster.health

client.index index: 'my-index', type: 'my-document', id: 1, body: { title: 'Test' }

client.indices.refresh index: 'my-index'

client.search index: 'my-index', body: { query: { match: { title: 'test' } } }
```

**Questions:**

- where I will define the details of my `elasticsearch cluster` in the code? the cluster is running at `http://localhost:9200/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation specifics, the elasticsearch gem wraps [elasticsearch-transport](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport) for connecting to a cluster and [elasticsearch-api](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-api) for accessing the elasticsearch API. From the documentation of elasticsearch-transport,

*In the simplest form, connect to Elasticsearch running on http://localhost:9200 without any configuration:*

So basically, `client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true` will by default connect to the cluster running at localhost:9200 (the same machine as your Rails app).

Go ahead and try executing `client.cluster.health` after establishing the connection and you'll get to know if it succeeded or not.

Moreover, if your cluster runs on a different server, you can use the following to connect to it:

```
es = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: http(s)://<path-to-cluster-server>
```